# convert HW IRQ to Linux IRQ

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, interrupt, irq

I have a HW_IRQ is shared between 2 kernel modules. *Module1* is loaded at the boot time and called: `request_irq(linux_irq1, handler1, IRQF_SHARED, ...);`. After booting up, I want to load the *Module2* that shared the same HW_IRQ with the *Module1*. I need to call `request_irq(linux_irq2, handler2, IRQF_SHARED, ...);`. Actually 'linux_irq2' is equal to 'linux_irq1', but in *Module2* I can not access to private data of *Module1*. Do you know how to convert HW_IRQ to 'linux_irq2' in *Module2*?

*Module2* as a patch of *Module1*, it has no Device Tree node.

Comment: You need to map your HW IRQ twice for both modules. It's done automatically by properly prepared Device Tree with `interrupt` reference for both devices. No special code is needed. Since you have no DT node for the second module, your architecture is broken. You need to redesign the solution by supplying necessary data from the first module to the second.

Comment: Since you have no DT node for the second module, your architecture is broken. You need to redesign the solution by supplying necessary data from the first module to the second. As a hackish workaround you may access the Device Tree node of the first module and get the interrupt from it.

Comment: Thanks @0andriy. I can convert HW irq to Linux irq as in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can map HW IRQ to Linux IRQ by this:

```
u32 irq;
struct irq_desc *desc;

for (irq = 0; irq < NR_IRQS; irq++) {
    desc = irq_to_desc(irq);
    if (desc && desc->irq_data.hwirq == hwirq)
        return desc->irq_data.irq;
}
```